# UWP App stops accepting Focus-Events until switching to another app and back

Tags: uwp, textbox, focus, uwp-xaml

we're developing a Universal Platform App which shows some unexpected behavior. Every now and then it's not possible anymore to focus a textbox. In fact you click/tap inside a textbox but it doesn't get highlighted and there is no blinking cursor inside. When you switch to another application and back or just press the windows key twice to open and close Windows start menu the problem disappears and the app response like expected.

I know this is a very rough description but after 30+ days we cannot isolate the cause any better.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

Markus

Comment: It looks the ui-thread was blocked, please post more code or share us with [mcve].

Comment: I had a similar guess, but it seems like that's not the case because the app is still responsive. I can navigate to other pages and everything looks like it should. Only TextBoxes are not being highlighted when focused. Downside of this is, they accept and display user input - but do not Update their Text-Property what leads to loss of user input.

Comment: It's hard to detect the problem with the description, could you share more code.

Comment: I agree, sadly it's not that easy to create a reproducible example because the behavior only occurs in very complex cases. I'm working on it and I'll share it here when I figure something out. My hope was to find somebody that might had the same issue and could give me some hint...

Comment: OK, if you have any updates, please comment below.